# Need to view Excel in Web Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to open an excel file in web browser using ASP.Net. Is any control to has this feature?.Help me to find that.

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-XML-File-in-Web-Browser-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: In my view it's not possible :(

Comment: I don't think it's possible without using Silverlight or something else messy that isn't well supported. Just let them download the file and view it. That's what users normally expect. The only other thing I can think of would involve hosting it in office 365 or google docs and then sharing the link. But that might have privacy or data protection issues, and also relies on your users having active accounts for those services - so probably not a great solution

Answer (score 1):

Telerik can help you with the RadSpreadsheet
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/spreadsheet.aspx